# If $G$ is finite simple and $H \le G$ has index $2m$, then an involution of $G$ is conjugate to one in $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

I have been trying to prove the following for a while now, with plenty of attempts and ideas, but no success.  I would appreciate a gentle nudge in the right direction.

Suppose that $G$ is a finite simple group with $|G|>2$.

a) Let $H \le G$, where $|G:H|=2m$, and $m$ is odd.  If $t \in G$ has order $2$, show that $t$ is conjugate in $G$ to some element of $H$.

b) Suppose that a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_8$ (of order $8$).  Show that $G$ has a unique conjugacy class of involutions.

For (a) I am given the hint to let $G$ act on the right cosets of $H$ via right multiplication.

Let $Ha$, $Hb$ be distinct right cosets of $H$ in $G$.  Then $Ha\cdot (a^{-1}b)=Haa^{-1}b=Hb$, so the action is transitive.  It follows that there is only one orbit, with size $2m$.  By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, this tells us that $|G:G_{Ha}|=2m$ for any $Ha \in G/H$ ($G_{Ha}$ is the stabilizer of $Ha$ in $G$).  I have been racking my brain trying to find a way to show that $t$ fixes some $Ha$, because then $Ha \cdot t = Hat = Ha$, and it follows that $Hata^{-1}=H$ and $ata^{-1} \in H$, giving the desired result.

I'm not sure how to use the assumptions that $G$ is simple and $|G:H|=2m$.  What I can say is that the kernel of the action of $G$ on $H$ must be trivial.  Already I mentioned that $|G:H|=2m$ gives us the size of the single orbit is $2m$, and this says that the $|G:G_{Ha}|=2m$ for each $Ha$.  I'm not sure what the significance of $m$ being odd is, because G/H is only a set and not a group (in this case).  I haven't managed to deduce any useful group properties from it, either.

Another possibility is to show that $|H|$ is divisible by $2$.  Then $H$ contains an involution which is contained in some Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$, and all of these (there must be more than one since $G$ is simple) are conjugate, so I think this may give us what we need.

Again, I'd appreciate a *hint* (only) on how to proceed.  Thanks.

Comment: For (a), you just need to observe that it the involution $t$ had no fixed points, then it would be an odd permutation. (b) seem to be much harder. It is proved in Theorem 7.3 of Gorenstein's book "Finite Groups" using Gr\"un's transfer theorem. Are you familiar with that result?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, I'll see where I can get with that.  No, I'm not familiar with that result.  This problem is from the final exam in I.M. Isaacs' first year graduate course in algebra, and in the preface of the corresponding book he states that he skips chapter 9 (on transfer) completely in the class.  So I don't think he intended for transfer to be used in the proof.

Comment: @DerekHolt Suppose $t$ fixes no element of $G/H$.  Let $\phi: G \to S_{2m}$.  Then $|\phi(t)|$ divides $|t|$, but $\mathrm{ker} \phi =1$, so $|\phi(t)|=2$, and $\phi(t)$ is a product of disjoint transpositions.  Since $t$ fixes no element of $G/H$, $\phi(t)$ must consist of exactly $m$ such transpositions... (cont.)

Comment: But $m$ is odd, and so $t$ induces an odd permutation on $G/H$, which in turn tells us that $G$ has a normal subgroup of index $2$, a contradiction of the simplicity of $G$.  It follows that $t$ fixes some $Ha \in G/H$, so $Ha \cdot t=Hat=Ha$.  Now we have $Hata^{-1}=H$, and $ata^{-1} \in H$, so $t$ is conjugate to some element of $H$. Does that work?

Comment: Yes that looks good for (a). Meanwhile Jack Schmidt and I have written out a proof of (b).

Comment: @DerekHolt Good, thanks.  I have been (slowly) working through the proof of (b) and will most likely have questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can continue Jack Schmidt's argument to complete the proof of (b) without  using transfer. A Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ of $G$ is generated by two involutions $s,t$, where $z=(st)^2$ is the central involution.

If $s$ is conjugate in $G$ to $z$ then, since $s$ and $sz$ are conjugate in $S$, all three involutions in the $4$-group $T = \langle s,z \rangle$ are conjugate in $G$. Since $|G:T| = 2m$ with $m$ odd, $t$ (and $tz$) must also be conjugate to them, and so all involutions in $G$ are conjugate. The same applies if $t$ and $z$ are conjugate.

Since Jack has shown that there are at most two classes of involutions, the only other possibility is that $s$ and $t$ are conjugate in $G$, but are not conjugate to $z$. In that case, $\langle s,z \rangle$ and $\langle t,z \rangle$ must be Sylow $2$-subgroups of $C_G(s)$ and $C_G(t)$. If $s^g=t$, then $g$ conjugates a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $C_G(s)$ to one of $C_G(t)$ and so, by Sylow's Theorem, we can choose $g$ such that $\langle s,z \rangle^g =\langle t,z \rangle$.

Now $S^g$ and $S$ are Sylow $2$-subgroups of $N_G(\langle t,z \rangle)$, so by Sylow's Theorem there exists $x \in N_G(\langle t,z \rangle)$ with $S^{gx}=S$, and so $\langle s,z \rangle^h =\langle t,z \rangle$ with $h = gx \in N_G(S)$. Since $\langle s,z \rangle$ and $\langle t,z \rangle$ are the only two Klein $4$-subgroups of $S$, we must also have $\langle t,z \rangle^h =\langle s,z \rangle$.

So conjugation by $h$ is inducing an outer automorphism of $S$ of even order, which is impossible because $N_G(S)/S$ has odd order.

Comment: (I'm very tired, sorry if this a dumb question.) I follow up to $g \in C_G(z)$. I know $S \cap S^g$ contains $\langle t,z\rangle$, but I don't see why it has to contain $s$. I follow everything after $g \in N_G(S)$. (and thanks, I had tried to prove the $s \sim t \not\sim z$ was impossible directly, but I could only do it using something like Alperin's fusion theorem).

Comment: Yes, I have missed out a step there. But $C_G(z)/\langle z \rangle$ has an abelian Sylow $2$-subgroup $S/\langle z \rangle$ so, working modulo $\langle z \rangle$, (the image of) $s$ conjugate to $t$ in $C_G(z)$ implies that $\langle s,z \rangle/\langle z \rangle$ is conjugate to $\langle t,z \rangle/\langle z \rangle$ in $N_{C_G(z)}(S)/\langle z \rangle$. So we can choose $g \in N_G(S)$.

Comment: Thanks! Looks good. If the OP doesn't know the trick about abelian Sylows, it is called "Burnside's fusion theorem" and is no harder than "Frattini argument" (you just use Sylow's theorem in some well chosen subgroups).

Comment: I've edited the last bit of the argument now, which I hope makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

For (b), I can use (a) to show that there are at most two conjugacy classes.

Let $P$ be a Sylow 2-subgroup, let $t$ be an involution distinct from the involution $z$ in $Z(P)$, and let $H=C_G(t)$ be the centralizer of $t$ in $G$. Since $t$ and $z$ are in $H$, we get that a Sylow 2-subgroup of $H$ is either of order 4 or 8.

Order 4:  [ In reality, this case can never occur. You prove this by transfer or fusion. ]

> If order 4, then $[G:H]=2m$, and so every involution is conjugate to either $t$, $tz$, or $z$, but $tz$ and $t$ are already conjugate in $P$.

Order 8:

> If order 8, then clearly $t$ is central in some other Sylow $P^g$, but since $z$ is the unique central involution of $P^g$, we get that $t=z^g$.

The other involutions are already handled:

> If $s$ is an arbitrary involution, then either $s$ is conjugate to $z$, $s=z^g$ and thus $s$ is central in $P^g$, or the centralizer $H=C_G(s)$ of $s$ has order not divisible by 8, and so  case 4 (strengthened by $s$ not conjugate to $z$) gives $s$ is conjugate to $t$.

In reality though, if the order 4 case ever happens you get that $G$ has a normal subgroup of index 2 by transfer.

Comment: Could you explain how we see that since $t$ and $z$ are in $H$ we get that a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $H$ is either of order $4$ or $8$?  I can see order $4$ ($\{1,t,z,tz\}$), but not order $8$.

Comment: A Sylow 2-subgroup of H cannot be bigger than a Sylow 2-subgroup of G, so 8 is the biggest. Lagrange says it must be 4 or 8. I'm just trying all possible numbers. You might be asking a different question: can 8 actually happen? If it was 8, it would mean that t was in the center of a Sylow 2-subgroup of G (not just H), but z is the center of P. How can that happen? Exactly when t and z are conjugate! Take $G=A_6$, $t=(1,2)(3,4)$, and $s=(1,3)(5,6)$. Then $z=(1,3)(2,4)$ generates the center of $P$, but $s,t,z$ are all conjugate in $A_6$, so their centralizers have the same order, 8.

Comment: I understand now.  I didn't know if there was a more specific reason to think that it would be 8, other than that it could be, in theory.  Thanks.

Comment: There are (transfer), but I was not using them. I was using a standard technique in finite groups: only finitely many cases, so check them all! Part of the art is organizing the cases, especially the ones that cannot happen.

Comment: Got it.  I plan on learning transfer at some point.  I understand most of your proof, but in the first box, what is the relevance of "but $tz$ and $t$ are already conjugate in $P$"?

Comment: THe mystery involution s must be conjugate to t, z, or tz. I want to prove it is actually conjugate to either t or z. The only missing case is when it is conjugate to tz, so s^g = tz. But (tz)^x = t for some x in P, so s^(gx) = (tz)^x = t, and s is conjugate to t.

Comment: I see now that we're starting with $t$ and $z$ and showing that every involution is conjugate to one of them to show that there are at most two conjugacy classes.  I didn't pick up on that before.  Thanks.